# "Python" comparing two lists and looking for a match when a list contains '':"(key values)

Tags: python

Im looking for an efficient way to match the hashes in both lists and print out what the match was and what the file should be against the database? Im all out of ideas, can anyone recommend a way to validated these against a database?

```
data_base=['9d377b10ce778c4938b3c7e2c63a229a : contraband_file1.jpg', '6bbaa34b19edd6c6fa06cccf29b33125 : contraband_file2.jpg', 'e4e7c3451a35944ca8697f9f2ac037f1 : contraband_file3.jpg', '1d6d9c72e3476d336e657b50a77aee05 : contraband_file4.gif']

hashed_files= ['6e3b028cc1972f6ad534b9fc1428eef6 : big.jpg', 'c9505a624181faa4be86cfe2af4b71eb : msc_asdf_logo.jpg', '6bbaa34b19edd6c6fa06cccf29b33125 : nothingtoseehere.docx', 'e4e7c3451a35944ca8697f9f2ac037f1 : StarWarsReview.docx', '0e89978428a4fe88fab1be364d998b57 : wargames.jpg']
```

Comment: Did you create those data structures yourself? They look a bit odd in that they resemble too closely what might be able to be re-structured as a dictionary. Do you have any control over how those are created?

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow and to the hole layout, it is a little hard to show as the data is comming from many scripts. The database was provided by our lecturer, exactly as it comes. I then had to create another list from a directory of downloaded files, hashed them and stored them into a list. my aim is now to compare the hashed files against the database and flag up if there is a match and what the file should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dictionaries and list iteration search:

```
data_base = {x.split(' : ')[0] : x.split(' : ')[1] for x in data_base}
hashed_files = {x.split(' : ')[1] : x.split(' : ')[0] for x in hashed_files}
matches = []
for file in hashed_files:
    if hashed_files[file] in data_base:
        matches.append((file, data_base[hashed_files[file]]))
```

Results with

```
>>> matches
[('StarWarsReview.docx', 'contraband_file3.jpg'), ('nothingtoseehere.docx', 'contraband_file2.jpg')]
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted this code into a new script and everything works perfectly as I wanted with some slight modifications. But in the code i am trying to implement it into is still having some issue  and doesnt work, but this has been a great help it has given be a base line to work from

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the python list and dictionary comprehension for this:

```
list_split1 = [s.split(' : ') for s in data_base]
list_split2 = [s.split(' : ') for s in hashed_files]
data_base_dict = {k:v for k,v in list_split1}
hashed_files_dict = {k:v for v,k in list_split2}
for f, h in hashed_files_dict.items(): #for python3.x --- for python2.x use .iteritems()
    if h in data_base_dict:
        print(f, data_base_dict[h])
```

this results in:

```
StarWarsReview.docx contraband_file3.jpg
nothingtoseehere.docx contraband_file2.jpg
```

Comment: Amazing, you guys are awesome, this one works perfectly with my code although its need some tweaks as its having some issues when i try to return (f, data_base_dict[h]) instead of print, but this is out put i was looking for :)